# Overriding Vuetify variables when building a Vue2+Vuetify app with Vite

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vite

I'm trying to migrate a Vue2+Vuetify app from Vue-CLI/Webpack to Vite. The app has a couple of SCSS files, `main.scss` and `variables.scss` with the latter imported by the former.

### main.scss

```css
@import 'variables';
// global style rules (omitted)
```

### variables.scss

```css
// override some Vuetify variables and define some variables of my own, e.g.
// Vuetify default is 48px
$data-table-mobile-row-min-height: 32px;

// Increase default height by 10px
// https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-date-picker/#sass-variables
$date-picker-table-height: 252px;
```

`main.scss` is imported in the root component, which means that:

1. rules in `main.scss` are applied to every component
2. variables in `variables.scss` can be referred to in any component without any additional imports
3. variables defined by Vuetify can be referred to in any component without any additional imports
4. variables in `variables.scss` override Vuetify variables with the same name

However, after migrating to Vite, only (1) still worked. I was able to resolve (2) and (3) by adding the following to `vite.config.js`

```js
export default defineConfig({
  // other config omitted

  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        // Make the variables defined in these files available to all components, without requiring an explicit
        // @import of the files themselves
        additionalData: `@import "./src/styles/variables"; @import "vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables";`
      },
    },
  },
});
```

However, it's still the case that (4) no longer works.

As far as I know, the [vuetify-loader](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/) is responsible for this behaviour when building with Vue-CLI, but it's not clear how to override Vuetify variables when building with Vite?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is accomplished with [`unplugin-vue-components`](https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-vue-components), the Vite equivalent of `vuetify-loader`.

Configure Vite to use `unplugin-vue-components` with its Vuetify resolver, which automatically imports the Vuetify components and styles upon use (like `vuetify-loader`):

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
import { VuetifyResolver } from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    ⋮
    Components({
      resolvers: [VuetifyResolver()],
    }),
  ],
})
```

*Note:* SCSS indented syntax is enabled by default, so `additionalData` must not contain semicolons, and each line must end with the newline character:

```js
// vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      sass: {
        // ❌ no semicolons for indented syntax
        // additionalData: `@import "./src/styles/variables"; @import "vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables";`

        // ✅
        additionalData: [
          '@import "./src/styles/variables"',
          '@import "vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables"',
          '', // end with newline
        ].join('\n'),
      },
    },
  },
})
```

The Vuetify plugin setup should import from `vuetify/lib/framework` instead of from `vuetify`, and it should **not** import the default Vuetify CSS:

```js
// plugins/vuetify.js
import Vue from 'vue'

// ❌ defeats dynamic imports from unplugin-vue-components
// import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
// import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

// ✅
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib/framework'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({/* options */})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-vuetify-global-scss-vars?file=vite.config.js)

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot! But adding @import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass' to App.vue in your Stackblitz example produces a runtime error [plugin:vite:css] Can't find stylesheet to import. Do you have any idea why?